# are these summations equal

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, summation

Give Function A:
$$ \frac{1}{2} \gamma X^2  - \frac{1}{2}\gamma \sum_{i=1}^N  n_k^2
$$

and Function B:
$$  \epsilon \sum_{i=1}^N |n_i| +  \frac{\eta}{\tau} \sum_{i=1}^N {n_i}^2$$

Can you show that when you combine A + B you get equation C:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \gamma X^2 +  \epsilon \sum_{i=1}^N |n_i| +  \frac{\eta*}{\tau} \sum_{i=1}^N {n_i}^2   $$

where

$$  \eta* = \eta - \frac{1}{2} \gamma \tau $$

I don't see how this term

$$ + \frac{\eta*}{\tau} \sum_{i=1}^N {n_i}^2   $$ is in equation C

Thank you.

Comment: What is meant by $\eta = \eta - \frac12\gamma\tau$? Why $\eta$ appears on both sides?

Comment: Can you clarify the summation indices and the equality on $\eta $?

Comment: Hi I forgot to put he * on eta.  What do you mean about the summation indcies? Thank you

Comment: I corrected the summation index. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
-\frac{1}{2}\gamma\sum_{i=1}^{N}n_{i}^{2}+\frac{\eta}{\tau}\sum_{i=1}^{N}n_{i}^{2}&=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\gamma+\frac{\eta}{\tau}\right)\sum_{i=1}^{N}n_{i}^{2}\\[10pt]
&=\frac{1}{\tau}\left(\eta-\frac{1}{2}\gamma\tau\right)\sum_{i=1}^{N}n_{i}^{2}\\[10pt]
&=\frac{\eta*}{\tau}\sum_{i=1}^{N}n_{i}^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you split the term in question into two according to your formula for eta*, you will find that the first term is the second term of function B, and the second term is the second term of function A.